# ubuntu is crashed while booting up

Tags: dual-boot

I'm dual booting W7 and Ubuntu (installed from Wubi). I've had it up and running a few times but today ,i have pressed power button multiple times while booting up and I'm getting a message from Windows Boot Manager when I select Ubuntu that wubildr.mbr is missing or corrupt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

i have installed on G drive and the .mbr file got corrupted.I thought of uninstalling it.But now G drive itself is is not opening.Lots of other data is also in G drive.Kindly help me in fixing this issue.am getting the below error when trying to open G drive.

G drive is not accessible because of an I/O device error.

How to proceed further.Because of this,windows boot up process is taking more time than usual

Answer (score 0):

The problem has caused because you directly turned off your system multiple time so it might be possible that  some bad sector have been created. Right now i can only suggest you to run system utility to check and fix problems related to your drive. you can do it by either of the way.

1. Go to command prompt and type following command

   chkdsk G:

Or you can run same utility by GUL mode.

1. In MY COMPUTER, Right click on G drive
2. Go to priperties
3. Go to tab "TOOLS"
4. Click on Check
5. Select both "Automatically Check and fix system errors" and "scan and attempt recovery for bad sectors"
6. Run it by clicking on Start.

Hope it works.

Comment: Ya i will try sumeet and let you know.